Nginx Reverse Proxy Not Forwarding Requests Correctly to Backend Server
"I am trying to use Nginx as a reverse proxy to solve the issue of CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing).
Here are the details:
Frontend project address: 127.0.0.1:5173
Backend API address: 127.0.0.1:8080
The frontend is calling backend APIs using axios at 127.0.0.1:5173/api/getname (Note that this is not on port 8080 because my frontend is listening on port 5173, so I thought I could proxy it to port 8080 via proxy_pass).
Here is my Nginx configuration:
Nginx
server {
    listen 5173;
    server_name localhost;

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
    }
}

My plan was to have the server listen on port 5173 and when a request comes in for localhost:5173/api, it should be proxied to localhost:8080. However, this setup does not seem to work. Why is that?
enter image description here
In reality, when I send a request to localhost:5173/api, Nginx does not forward this request to localhost:8080."

"I asked ChatGPT-4 about the correct way to write an Nginx reverse proxy configuration. Here is one approach I learned:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        # Proxy the frontend application
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5173;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /api/ {
        # Proxy the backend API
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

However, I'm not sure why my previous approach did not work. I did ask GPT about it but didn't receive the answer I was looking for, which is why I'm asking here.Is it possible that doing so causes a port conflict, which might have led to the failure?"
